# JVM suddenly does very long minor collections

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I have a Tomcat (7.0.71) running in JDK8u91 (on Solaris 10) with a rather large heap of 24GB (-Xmx24000m, -XX:MaxNewSize=64m). I'm using the ParNewGC for new and CMS for old generation, with 3 threads.

Normally, minor collections are fast (<250ms). At seemingly random times (can't correlate it with high application or system load) the minor collections start to take a ridiculously long time, like 60 or even 480 seconds!

```
2017-05-24T21:18:45.083+0200: 21126.227: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-05-24T21:18:45.084+0200: 21126.228: [ParNew: 59008K->5491K(59008K), 0.1586398 secs] 7944703K->7892598K(13640280K), 0.1591188 secs] [Times: user=0.34 sys=0.01, real=0.16 secs] 
2017-05-24T21:18:46.632+0200: 21127.776: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-05-24T21:18:46.632+0200: 21127.776: [ParNew: 57971K->6528K(59008K), 0.2516826 secs] 7945078K->7921839K(13640280K), 0.2520740 secs] [Times: user=0.58 sys=0.01, real=0.25 secs] 
==> 2017-05-24T21:19:06.366+0200: 21147.510: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-05-24T21:19:06.367+0200: 21147.510: [ParNew: 59008K->6528K(59008K), 61.3857565 secs] 8486461K->8447939K(13640280K), 61.3866299 secs] [Times: user=106.90 sys=1.07, real=61.39 secs] 
==> 2017-05-24T21:20:08.244+0200: 21209.386: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) 2017-05-24T21:20:08.244+0200: 21209.386: [ParNew: 59008K->6528K(59008K), 476.5251482 secs] 8500419K->8471560K(13640280K), 476.5259850 secs] [Times: user=848.62 sys=4.66, real=476.53 secs] 
2017-05-24T21:28:05.095+0200: 21686.223: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) 2017-05-24T21:28:05.095+0200: 21686.223: [ParNew: 56300K->6528K(59008K), 0.3201989 secs] 8526965K->8496807K(13640280K), 0.3206126 secs] [Times: user=0.71 sys=0.01, real=0.32 secs]
```

The VM recovers after these incidents, but of course the application is unavailable during these pauses. We have tried making young gen smaller or larger, but these times keep coming back.

We don't see any unexpected issues with the major collections (they of course take some time with 24GB heap). I know that the total heap size influences also minor collection times (card scan time) but I don't see how it could cause those jumps in time!

I'm absolutely clueless what could cause those delays. Any hints?

CU, Joe

Comment: Enable full gc logging and analyze the results.  My initial guess would be finalizers.

Comment: We have the following flags active:

-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=3 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=65 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M

And those lines I posted are what we see. Which other flags could I enable?

Comment: But finalizers are a good hint! We'll check on those

Comment: For now we have `                        -verbose:gc                        -XX:+PrintGCDetails                        -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps                        -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps                        -Xloggc:gc-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')-$$$$.log                        -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` in a project based on                     https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/01/useful-jvm-flags-part-8-gc-logging/
 - we do not yet have full production logs so I do not know how useful they are.   The IBM JVM has very good diagnostic tools.

Comment: Speaking of references, you need to add -XX:+PrintReferenceGC, see also http://blog.ragozin.info/2016/10/hotspot-jvm-garbage-collection-options.html for some more useful options

Comment: How often those spikes happen?

Comment: The spikes happen at irregular intervals. Until today, we had like 3-5 occurrences of GC pauses of >30 secs. Today, we had 2 phases of ~20 mins where minor GCs would happen back to back, each one taking 6-8 seconds. But no very long collections. Haven't found any pattern so far

Comment: I added the following flags -XX:+PrintReferenceGC
-XX:+PrintJNIGCStalls
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy
-XX:+PrintGCCause

Comment: After adding the switches above, we had another occasion of a 58 second pause. I made a gist https://gist.github.com/jammann/94ceb9acb4483db83241a00aa856ff94 with some comments, added what I think are surrounding lines from other GCs. The line which informs about the long delay looks garbled somehow? Can it be that a CMS concurrent mark and a minor ParGC ran at the same time?? Could those be blocking each other?